# I am on ubuntu 2.31.1 and I need to manually fsck

Tags: fsck

The error message I am getting is:

```
(/dev/mapper/isw_dbjigffjdb_RADIOIMSVolume2 contains a file system with errors, c heck forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

(/dev/mapper/isw_dbjigffjdb_RADIOIMSVolume2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
                      (i.e., without -a or -p options)
    fsck exited with status code 4
    The root filesystem on  /dev/mapper/isw_dbjigffjdb_RADIOIMSVolume2 requires a manual fsck
```

How do I fix this?

I have tried to look at other questions about this but I cannot find anything to help me out. I think I'm on a version on which people don't use. I am also on an MSI laptop so I have quite a few problems here and there but I can reslove those.

[image: photograph of laptop display showing busybox initramfs]

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 2.31.1 or anything even close to that.

Comment: im also seeing a 1:1.27.2ubuntu3.3 in there

Comment: that is the version number of some package; but you've not given it any context that allows us to look up what you're using; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* so 2.31.1 would mean you're using a 2002.31th month release; but Ubuntu only started releasing in 2004 & no year has 31 months....

Comment: I have no idea where you are getting this stuff. Look at system setting / details

Comment: i posted an image that might help i have no clue, and im a person with no experience with computers so im very new to this, so please forgive my stupidity

Comment: `busybox | 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3  | bionic-updates/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` so Ubuntu 18.04 / bionic.  Have you booted *live* media and tried to check your file-systems? as it suggests (ie. `fsck`)

Comment: i do not have any recollection of checking file systems or booting live media 
(i need some more details into "booted live media"

Answer (score 2):

At the `initramfs` prompt you will need to enter:

```
fsck /dev/mapper/volume
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You must replace `volume` with the volume that needs the `fsck`. In this case it starts with `isw_db...` and ends in `...Volume2`.

You must enter each character exactly; it is case-sensitive. You may be able to use tab completion after typing the first few characters.

Comment: thank you for helping me